# How to delay KO binding until external template is loaded?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm building my SPA using AMD modules, RequireJS, and KnockoutJS for the 2-way binding. It's coming together fairly nicely but I am running into an issue.

You can't ko.applyBindings to a section in the page, that is loaded from an external template file, until after the template is fully loaded. I'm using the standard text!... template loader. How can I delay binding until the external template is finished loading? Is there an event hook?

Thanks a lot for any advice :-)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers. It will automatically load your templates via the text plugin at the right time and wait to render

Comment: I highly recommend watching Steve Sanderson's NDC 2014 [video](https://vimeo.com/97519516). Starting at 34:00 in the video he shows how to bundle Knockout JS files when using RequireJS. This will allow you to load external templates upfront rather than asynchronously. This is not a silver bullet, but it does present a new option which will cut down on HTTP requests and give your DOM access to your templates immediately.

Comment: @300baud: This is very intriguing. I've always wanted to learn Gulp, but may have to do that a little later when I have more time. Thank you for that link!

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: I'll give this a try after work today. I think you may have solved my problem!

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the replies. I greatly appreciate you both sharing the knowledge :-)

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: Very, very cool KO library BTW! I'm certain this would work fine for a multi-page app but I don't see how this is going to work for a SPA. My main index page only loads once, then I use the requirejs-router to load the different viewModels which pull their html content files and insert into the main content section on the index page. Does that make sense? I don't see how I can use knokcout-amd-helpers in this scenario/app :-(

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: I actually do have this working to load my index page, but then the issue comes when I want to load a different viewModel and template into that same main content section.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: Idea: Can I make the template name string an observable on the IndexViewModel? Then I could just change that template name observable to load the next content template. Would this work?

Comment: Yes my idea above works perfectly! You can use an observable in the 'template: { name: templObsrv }` to dynamically change the SPA main content section from your viewModel. Well done @RPNiemeyer :-)

So my SPA is using RequireJs, RequireJS-router, KnockoutJs, knockout-amd-helpers to manage external templates and lots of Postbox messages to loosely couple the logic tiers and KO components. I'm really, really happy with how this all works together.

Comment: @Locohost - yes- I generally bind a template/module against an observable and swap different views in and out

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in @RPNiemeyer first comment. The kncokout-amd-helpers is working perfectly. See my comment about 'works perfectly' above.

If you want to load external templates in Knockout SPA, definitely use his KO plugin!